How to save trained YOLOv8 model?
I have successfully trained a YOLOv8 model on my custom dataset, and it is working well. However, I am now facing issues with saving and loading the trained model.
To save the model, I used the following code:
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "yolo_model.pt")
While this code snippet seems to save the model without any errors, I'm encountering difficulties when trying to load it back for inference. Additionally, I noticed that whenever I shut down my laptop and reopen it, I need to rerun the entire training process from scratch.
Could someone please guide me on the correct way to save and load the YOLOv8 model so that I can avoid retraining it every time and ensure smooth inference? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
I attempted to save my trained YOLOv8 model using the torch.save() function, providing the model's state dictionary as an argument and saving it to a file named 'yolo_model.pt'. I expected this process to successfully save the model parameters to the specified file, allowing me to load it later for inference without any issues. However, when I tried to load the saved model using torch.load() function, I encountered errors or unexpected behavior. Additionally, I noticed that whenever I shut down my laptop and reopened it, I had to rerun the entire training process from scratch, which is not the desired behavior. I'm seeking guidance on the correct approach to save and load the YOLOv8 model properly to avoid these issues and ensure seamless inference.

If you're using something like the following to train:
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
results = model.train(data="coco8.yaml", epochs=100, imgsz=640)

Then the weights will be saved in the "weights" folder under best.pt (best performing model) and last.pt (weights from the last epoch). In your inference script you should be able to load one of these models with:
model = YOLO("path/to/best.pt")  # load a custom trained model

Training a model with YoloV8
Inference with YoloV8
